# How do I add a command to bash history without executing it?

Tags: bash

Use case is:

I type a long command and then I realize I need to run something else first.

I usually run it then CTRL C immediately.

I guess I could also do `echo "command" >> $HISTFILE`, but that won't work with quotes.

Comment: My usual habit is Ctrl+A, Ctrl+K to move the line into the cut buffer, and Ctrl+Y to paste it later -- but Matti's variant is better.

Comment: I usually just press Ctrl-C once I've finished typing out the entire command. The command remains visible on-screen, but doesn't execute. I run the other command, then select the still-visible command (to copy it) and paste it.

Comment: simple hack.  say you want to **git commit -am "done"**.  then you realize you aren't done.  ctrl-a back to the start of the command, add 'x' (for example), giving **xgit commit -am "done"**.  which errors out but goes in history.  later on, just go back in history, ctrl-a and remove the 'x'.  make sure 'x' + command is actually not a valid command though.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate of [this question on Super User](http://superuser.com/q/135651/269989)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As an alternative to editing the history you could use <kbd>Ctrl-U</kbd> to cut the line (note that this cuts backward from the cursor, so it should be at the end), and <kbd>Ctrl-Y</kbd> to paste it back later. <kbd>Meta-Y</kbd> used after <kbd>Ctrl-Y</kbd> will cycle through the different cut values so you can get back to previous ones as well.

Comment: This works *exactly* as the OP wants.  I know because I wanted the same thing and a very kind soul told me this. I now use it *all the time* when I've typed a long command and thought "oh, want to this other thing first".

Answer (score 27):

Just use `history -s arg`.

> -s   The args are added to the end of the history list as a single entry.

http://ss64.com/bash/history.html

Comment: any way to do this from inside a bash script?

Answer (score 14):

Another alternative is to put a hash at the front of the line:

```
# echo this command will not execute, but it will be in the history.
```

Comment: If you've got a thing for editing quickly, use <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> to go to the beginning of the line, as <kbd>End</kbd> is usually further away.

Comment: Quicker still, there's a default binding that does exactly this: Meta-# is `insert-comment`, which is essentially the same as move to beginning-of-line, insert #, execute command

Answer (score 5):

You can edit the `~/.bash_history` file.

Comment: This isn't helpful for the scenario in the OP's question.

Answer (score 4):

This might work for you:

```
Alt-# or insert-comment will change the command into a comment and store it in command history.
```

If the command is retrieved from the history using Ctr-p then:

```
Alt--1 Alt-# will remove the comment and execute the command.
```

Comment: ++, but you should call the modifier key `Meta`, not `Alt`, as it won't be `Alt` on all platforms (at least by default).

Comment: The latter shortcut does not work here.

Comment: Press `alt` + `#`.

This inserts `#` at beginning of the command and store it in command history.

Press `ctrl` + `p` to retrieve the previous command.

Press `alt` + `1` then `alt` + `#` to remove the comment and execute the command.